# T-SQL: "Compress" rows with equal values to one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a chance to show only one row if there are any rows with same values?

I've the following scenario:

> ID | Column A | Column B | Column C
>
> 1  |  2      |    'test' |     5
>
> 2  |  3      |     'test'|     6
>
> 3  |  2      |     'test'|      5

In this scenario I want only show the following resultset:

> ID | Column A | Column B | Column C
>
> 1  |  2      |    'test' |     5
>
> 2  |  3      |     'test'|     6

Thanks for your help.

Regards, pro

Comment: [`Group By`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this :

With cte As
( Select  * , row_number() over (partition by ColumnA, ColumnB,ColumnC
 order by ID ) as myrownumber from myTable
)
Select * from cte where myrownumber=1
```

Comment: @JNK bracket was missing .Now rectified !

Answer (score 6):

Your rows are not exact duplicates, because of the id column.  If you don't care which value of the id appears, you can do what you want as:

```
select max(id) as id, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
from t
group by ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
```

If you don't need the id at all, this is simpler:

```
select distinct ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, column1,column2,colum3 from
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by column1,column2,colum3 order by id) as sno 
    from table
) as t
where sno=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    ID      TINYINT     NOT NULL,
    colA    TINYINT     NOT NULL,
    colB    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    colC    TINYINT     NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #test VALUES (1,2, 'test', 5);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES (2,3, 'test', 6);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES (3,2, 'test', 5);

SELECT 
    ID,
    ColA,
    ColB,
    ColC
FROM 
(   
    SELECT 
        ID,
        ColA,
        ColB,
        ColC,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY ColA DESC) AS RowNum
      FROM #test
) AS WorkTable
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: When i opened this question there wasn't any answer! Surprising to see these many answers by the time i wrote the script and pasted here.